# Why shouldn't I host my web server on my own PC?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting

If this is a terrible question, then I'm sorry but please don't down-vote me into oblivion lol. I also searched but figured it deserved it's own thread because my specs aren't the same as any I saw listed.

Anyways, I've ran dedicated servers for years and paying for them monthly is adding up, as my sites aren't running ads. I need to run 6 automated WordPress blogs and a small crypto-trading and management platform. What would be the down-sides of hosting my own web server? I don't game or anything, so I'm not worried about it using my resources. Are there any game-changers that remove it from being a decent viable option? Is there a good Docker for web-hosting or will I need to spin up a new Linux VM?

Pros:

- Gigabit connection that's always wide-open
- 32GB DDR4 RAM
- Ryzen 7 - 3.9 GHz
- 30 TB Storage

  - --> 5 TB NVMe Storage - Most data will be hosted here.
  - --> 5 TB SSD Storage - Maybe use this for RAID?
  - --> 20 TB HDD Storage - Videos will be hosted here.

Cons:

- Windows 10 (but I can create VM or Docker)

That would save a good bit of money per month if I were to rent a server with comparable specs.

Comment: I thought this question had been asked here before (by someone else) but I can't find it right now. It would be useful to have a good reference answer for "why not host at home".

Comment: Are any of these sites or services for customers that pay you for hosting?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but I will say I hosted my own personal web sites at home until one fateful day in 2004 when one of them appeared on the front page of slashdot. I moved it out within the hour, and I have not hosted anything public facing at home since. More recently I've had pages appear on Hacker News and similar sites, so I would not move back even with a "gigabit" home connection (hint: is it symmetric? Very unlikely if it's residential).

Comment: @joeqwerty No, I do not sell hosting. Seems that market is dominated right now.

Comment: well, may be you should (host it) but by def. it's offtopic here: "Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 5):

I don't know that there is a "one-size-fits-all" answer for your question.  However, like considerations for any hosting situation, there are lots of things to think about when you consider hosting at home.  For example:

- Volume of Traffic: (Do you have any information/Statistics on current volumes? What is the request demand? ...both in hardware resources as well as feed capacity.)
- Reliability/availability requirements: (What happens if your system is unreachable?)
- Connection speed, quality, reliability: (You say gigabit connection. Are there guaranteed speeds and what are the u/d thresholds? ...and...
- Provider restrictions: (Is this a dedicated data line like a T1, T3, C6, C12, etc? or is it some thing like home cable/internet service like Comcast/Verizon/Warner/etc?)
  (as Michael Hampton mentioned) is the line symmetric? - for example, if you have a cable service like Comcast, you might have 300Mbps down, but the upload speeds are governed at 5, 10 or 15 Mbps up. This means that your response service will be limited to that maximum bandwidth of 5-15Mbps - quite slow actually) 
  What kind of outages has the provider had in the past? What are the Service SLAs?)
  Many providers have limits or policies against high-consumption on a residential line and may require a dedicated data line)
- Uninterrupted Power: (What is your power grid reliability? Do you have adequate UPS, generator?)
- System Security: (What kind of information is stored on the system? What experience do you have with system security/hacking?)

Ultimately,

- If you are hosting your own/friends/family personal blogs, etc. with no real requirements for availability, reliability, speed...
- If the access traffic won't violate your TOS with your provider
- if there is no NPI/PPI/PHI (non-public information, personal private information, personal health information), credit card, identify, banking, etc. information on the system... and/or you don't have some other sensitive data on the system.

Then, self-hosting at home may be ok for you...

However, it's also a good idea to keep in mind security and the ability to keep the system safe so that the system doesn't fall victim to compromise, use as a launch-point for attacks on other systems (which could open you up to liability), etc.

disclaimer: I'm not an attorney, and I don't play one on TV. I can't and won't give legal advice. These are just questions that I ask in this type of situation.

I hope this helps :-)
scott